# How can I format a USB drive as limited user without administrative privileges on Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, usb-flash-drive, formatting

I'm trying to format my corrupted USB drive from school, where the Windows formatting tool has been disabled by the Administrator. Is there any alternative utility I can use? (preferably portable, since I can't install most programs without administrative privileges)

Comment: May not be the answer you are looking for however, I work as a technician in an education establishment, if you require your USB drive formating, just ask the school Technicians to do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the *tool* that has been disabled; it's the access to *raw drive itself*. (If I remember correctly, it's even the default setting to only allow Administrators to format drives.)

Without raw access to the drive, no tool of any kind will be able to format it.